# Fit website on iphone and ipad screen viewport?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, ipad, viewport

Before Apple released the last iOS update 9.3.1 on March 2016, all my webistes use to fit within the screen of an iphone (landscape mode) and ipad (portrait and landscape).

After the release, my sites appear zoomed and I have to swipe in/out in order to make the website fit the entire screen again. I tried many things that I found on different forums but none helped...

The tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` use to make it, and suddenly stopped working. Any idea?

You can see an example at `www.buenosaireshelicopter.com`

[See site after iOS 9.3.1 update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naQiZ.jpg)

[See site before iOS 9.3.1 update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TorUE.jpg)

Comment: do you have media queries in your css? Post your css code edit: I found your css, let me look

Comment: I have media queries for small screen resolutions, I did have them before this update and all worked fine. I haven't changed anything since then but my site is no longer displayed the same way

Answer (score 1):

I use this for my websites. It may be overkill, but I've never had a problem.

```css
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
/* iPhone 6 landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px)
  and (max-device-width: 667px)
  and (orientation: landscape)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
{ }

/* iPhone 6 portrait */
@media only screen
  and (min-device-width: 375px)
  and (max-device-width: 667px)
  and (orientation: portrait)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
{ }

/* iPhone 6 Plus landscape */
@media only screen
  and (min-device-width: 414px)
  and (max-device-width: 736px)
  and (orientation: landscape)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
{ }

/* iPhone 6 Plus portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
{ }

/* iPhone 6 and 6 Plus */
@media only screen
  and (max-device-width: 640px),
  only screen and (max-device-width: 667px),
  only screen and (max-width: 480px)
{ }

/* Apple Watch */
@media
  (max-device-width: 42mm)
  and (min-device-width: 38mm)
{ }
```

Comment: I just copied your media queries to my css but nothing changed :(

Comment: did you delete the css cache? what browser are you viewing it in?

Comment: yep, does it work fine for you now? cause it doesn't make any difference here

Comment: let me go to your page and copy the html and css and recreate it. Give me a while

Comment: sorry, I couldnt tell because I don't have all of your images. Let me look in Firefox with web dev tools